# How to migrate youtube api desktop applications and web server applications from v2 to v3

Tags: c#, php, youtube-api

Both my webserver and desktop application have stopped working for some weeks. The webserver says something about accounts not being linked(youtube - googel) when they in fact are and the desktop app written in c# outputs a 401 error.

As all credentials are correct I assume this googel company changed their api from v2 to v3 without further notice and this is their way of stating that. Proof for that is that in the console there is no v2, only youtube data api v3.

How do I migrate from v2 to v3 regarding the php-version and the desktop c# version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is getting an error about accounts not being linked, then it's because you're authenticating as a Google Account that's not linked to a YouTube channel, and migrating from v2 to v3 won't resolve that for you. [This blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html) has more details.

The YouTube GData API v2 has never been listed in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)—it predates the existence of that console.

v2 of the GData API remains supported as of this writing, although we of course do encourage developers to start their v3 migrations. There are a handful of examples for using both [PHP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php) and [.NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet) against the v3 API, and more will be added over time. There are a few guides out there to help understand some concepts that are of importance in v3, like [using channel ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids) and [moving to OAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth).

Comment: The question is: Can you already migrate to v3? v3 lacks many features and especially very important metadata settings. Thus, issue requests seem to be processed very slowly.

Comment: Which metadata settings in particular do you mean? There are admittedly a number of things in v2 that aren't in v3.

Comment: [#4620](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4620), as mentioned there: videoresponse, comments, rating comments, rating, etc. Basically many "advanced" settings.